# Difficulty writing .png file python

Tags: python, encoding, bin, contextio

I'm trying to write a .png file that I retrieve from the web with Python.

```
with open(fileName, 'w+') as f: 
      f.write(data)
```

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried to do `data.encode('utf-8')`, but when I use magic with Python to get the mime type, it detects it as a .bin file.

Is there any defined way to handle this? This happens some times and not others.

Here's some more information:

[Github link to code](https://github.com/contextio/Python-ContextIO/blob/master/contextio/__init__.py#L1710)

[API reference](https://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/files/content)

Comment: You seem to be receiving your data from the HTTP request as `unicode` instead of `str` (or `bytes` on Python3). That's wrong, since your binary PNG data isn't text, and unicode makes no sense in the context of binary data. Can you post the code you're using to fetch the file from the web?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open(fileName, 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: This is required (on Windows), but not necessarily sufficient. It looks as if the OP is receiving the data from the HTTP request as `unicode` - which can't be right since it's not text data, and won't work for writing it to a file unless he decodes it with the exact same encoding that was used to encode the data.

Comment: I tried it already. How would other Python modules know that it's in binary? The one's I'm using accept only a file path.